# Kotlin - Iterate over Class properties

Tags: class, kotlin, for-loop

Quick question, let's say we have this code:

```
fun main() {
    val instance = Random(1, "B", 3)
    for(__?__) {
        println(__?__)
    }
}

class Random(
    val A: Int,
    val B: String,
    val C: Int,
) {}
```

What should I add in places of `__?__` so that the program will print out all properities of `instance`?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal here? While iterating is clearly possible, there's very probably a better design which wouldn't need it. For example, instead of separate properties, should they be a structure such as a list or map? Or if this is for serialisation, there are libraries which can do it far better. (contd…)

Comment: Reflection is needed for frameworks, plugins, and build tools, but it's very rarely* appropriate in normal application code; it's slow, fragile, insecure, ugly, hard to do safely, hard to maintain, and a strong code smell. This approach might be appropriate in dynamic/scripting languages, but strongly-typed OO language like Kotlin provide much better ways to structure applications. (* I think I've resorted to it once in the last half-decade. And that was in a sort of mini-framework.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection:

```
class Random(
  val A: Int,
  val B: String,
  val C: Int,
) {}

val instance = Random(1, "B", 3)

for(field in instance::class.java.declaredFields) {
  field.isAccessible = true
  println(field.name + ": " + field.get(instance).toString())
}
```

Output:

```
A: 1
B: B
C: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing answer provides a solution using Java reflection. Alternatively, we can do this using the Kotlin reflection:

```kotlin
for (prop in Random::class.memberProperties) {
    prop.isAccessible = true
    println("${prop.name} = ${prop.get(instance)}")
}
```

Kotlin reflection works for multiplatform projects, not only for the JVM target. Also, it understands Kotlin properties, while Java does only recognize fields and methods.